# Winform won't resize when setting Size property

Tags: c#, winforms, window-resize

I have a WinForm that is used to host a WebBrowser control.  I want to dynamically resize the form based on the document size that the browser loads.

I can successfully read the document size from within the WebBrowser control and I set the form size based on that, but the form simply will not resize.

The resize is within the WebBrowsers DocumentCompleted event:

```
private void ViewWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewWebBrowser.Height = ViewWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Height;
    ViewWebBrowser.Width = ViewWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Width;
    Size = new Size(ViewWebBrowser.Width, ViewWebBrowser.Height);
}
```

This event fires just fine, the document loads and the document dimensions are detected as expected and they are correct based on the page I'm loading, but Size is always 37x38 coming out of the event handler.  Here's a screenshot of the debugger at a breakpoint:

[image]

I also tried converting pixels to points, but this had the same result.  Size was still 37x38.

```
private void ViewWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    ViewWebBrowser.Height = Convert.ToInt32(ViewWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Height * 72 / g.DpiY);
    ViewWebBrowser.Width = Convert.ToInt32(ViewWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Width * 72 / g.DpiX);
    Size = new Size(ViewWebBrowser.Width, ViewWebBrowser.Height);
}
```

The WebBrowser control loads the document during the form's `Activated` event:

```
private void WebBrowserView_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewWebBrowser.Navigate(URL); 
}
```

`URL` is a public string property set by a presenter.  The presenter does not set any size properties on the form.

`AutoSize` on the form is set to false.  The only properties on the form that I've changed from the default are `Text` and `FormBorderStyle` which is set to `SizableToolWindow`.

In addition to a new `Size` structure, I've also tried setting the `Height` and `Width` properties independently with the same result.

`MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` are both set to 0,0.  Setting `MinimumSize` to 1,1 does not change anything.

`DockStyle` on the WebBrowser control is set to `Fill` so I'm only setting `Size` on the form.

Why won't the form accept the new Size?

**EDIT:**

Here is the full class of the form:

```
public partial class WebBrowserView : Form, IWebBrowserView
{
    public WebBrowserView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string URL { private get; set; }

    private void WebBrowserView_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewWebBrowser.Navigate(URL);
    }

    private void ViewWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newHeight = ViewWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Height;
        var newWidth = ViewWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Width;
        ViewWebBrowser.Height = newHeight;
        ViewWebBrowser.Width = newWidth;
        this.Size = new Size(ViewWebBrowser.Width, ViewWebBrowser.Height);
    }

    private void WebBrowserView_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewWebBrowser.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Stupid question, but can you set `this.Size` rather than just `Size` and confirm it still fails.

Comment: If you can't increase the `Size`, that could be due to something changing it somewhere else or due to `MaxSize`.

Comment: First of all you're trying to set your window size to `[37 38]`which is insanely small ( considering current resolutions ) and could be "blocked" by `MinimumSize` property. Try changing `MinimumSize` first to be `[1 1]` and then try again to set the size.

Comment: @johnjps111 Yes, I've tried that also.  Same thing...

Comment: @Sinatr Sorry, forgot to mention that in the question.  MinSize and MaxSize are both set to 0,0

Comment: @squillman Reading **Remarks** section of [`MinimumSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that _"If this property is set to a Size object that is 0 in height and 0 in width, the form will have no minimum size beyond the limits set by Windows."_ which can prevent sizes like the one you want.

Comment: @m.rogalski No, 37x38 is the resulting size after I try to set it.  I just tried setting `MinimumSize` to 1,1 but that didn't change things.

Comment: Are there any child objects of larger size?

Comment: Have you tried to just call `this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 128);` inside and check if that works? Maybe there's some threading issue or whatever?

Comment: does the form resize when you plug in fixed values like 100, 100 ?

Comment: @johnjps111 No, no child objects.  The WebBrowser is the only control and it's dock is set to fill.

Comment: @MongZhu Yes.  I can set the height and width from the View and it resizes.  It just does not resize when dynamically setting it.

Comment: @m.rogalski Yes, setting `Size` to a new hardcoded size does resize the form.

Comment: I can assume that you're setting not the form size but some internal control instead. Can you show the whole definition of that class?

Comment: @m.rogalski I am setting only the form size.  The web browser control has dock set to Fill so it should resize itself when the form resizes.  I've edited in the full definition.

Comment: You can't have the WebBrowser set to Dock.Fill.

Comment: Try something adding `SuspendLayout();` at the top of handler method and after changing the size use `ResumeLayout();`

Comment: @LarsTech Dock is definitely set to Fill on teh WebBrowser

Comment: Yes, I'm telling you to stop doing that.

Comment: It's against your manual resize ;)

Comment: @m.rogalski `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` did it!  Post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the code, everything should work as intended but there is something called `pending layout requests` in `WinForms` which requests an update for the layout. These changes are applied after invalidation of the UI so it is recommended to use [`SuspendLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) method before updating crucial layout/visual elements and then call [`ResumeLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53zat12(v=vs.110).aspx) to apply these pending layout requests.

To apply these changes simply do :

```
void ViewWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    SuspendLayout();
    ViewWebBrowser.Height = ViewWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Height;
    ViewWebBrowser.Width = ViewWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Width;
    Size = new Size(ViewWebBrowser.Width, ViewWebBrowser.Height);
    ResumeLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ScrollRectangle property instead:

```
ViewWebBrowser.Height = ViewWebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
ViewWebBrowser.Width = ViewWebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
```

Per the comment thread, remove the Dock style:

```
ViewWebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.None;
```

Using Fill will interfere with your height and width measurements.

Comment: Thanks, but same result...  It's reading the document properties just fine.

Comment: Re: dock style.  I get what you're saying.  That would probably work just fine as well, but adding `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` to the begging and end of the handler did the trick.  Thanks, though!  I appreciate the suggestions.