# C# DataSet is not updated after updating the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to update the data grid view (move a row to a new index). I can't update it directly because the data grid view is bound so I am doing this using the dataTable.

```
  var dataTable = ((DataView)dataGridViewWebFields.DataSource).Table;
            var dataGridRow = dataGridViewWebFields.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(fieldName));
            if (dataGridRow != null && dataGridRow.Index != newIndex)
            {
                var dataTableRow = GetWebFieldFromDataGridViewRow(dataGridRow);
                var dataViewRow = dataGridViewWebFields.Rows[newIndex];
                dataViewRow.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridRow.DefaultCellStyle;
                var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = dataTableRow.ItemArray;
                dataTable.Rows.Remove(dataTableRow);
                dataTableRow.Index = newIndex;
                dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, newIndex);
                dataGridViewWebFields.DataSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
            }
```

The problem is that after I am saving this to the database and refreshing the control, the state of the data grid view is back to the default (before the changes). I think that something is not updated correctly on the DataSet. Can you guide me on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If that's `WinForms` have you tried with `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()`? Like in [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984883/winform-wont-resize-when-setting-size-property/45985477#45985477)

Comment: @Mateusz I tried it now. It doesn't work

Comment: Can you guide me on what am I doing wrong?